# Series expansion of explicit functions

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion, variable-definitions

For the following input,

```
zv[u_, v_] :=   v + zv1[ u, v]/u;
mvu[u, v] := D[zv[u, v], u];
Series[mvu[u, v], {u, 0, 1}]
```

the output is

```
-(zv1[0,v]/u^2)+1/2 zv1^(2,0)[0,v]+1/3 u zv1^(3,0)[0,v]+O[u^2]
```

I want the series expansion without expansion of zv1[u, v] around 0 (basically the output should be

```
 zv1^(1,0)[u,v]/u - zv1[u,v]/u^2
```

Is there a general method to do this?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `Series[mvu[u + h, v], {h, 0, 1}]`? You want the series expansion _around what value_?

Comment: I am looking for the series expansion of mvu[u, v] around u = 0 without expanding zv1[u, v] as zv1[0, v] + zv1^(1, 0)[0,v]u + O[u^2].